# How do I use ANTLR's generated parser and lexer?

Tags: java, antlr

I created the antlr4 grammar file `Jay.g4` and generated the `JayLexer.java` and `JayParser.java`. I compiled these to create `JayLexer.class` and `JayParser.class`.

My question is: how do I use those generated sources with Java? 
I am using the NetBeans IDE and I don't know how to integrate the lexer and parser into my project and make them work correctly.

Answer (score 7):

If you're going to venture further, I recommend [The Definitive Antlr 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference). From the [Antlr documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/ANTLR+4+Documentation), you can download/see some sample code, including this:

```
final LexerGrammar lg = (LexerGrammar) Grammar.load(lexerGrammarFileName);
final Grammar pg = Grammar.load(parserGrammarFileName, lg);
ANTLRFileStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(fileNameToParse);
LexerInterpreter lexEngine = lg.createLexerInterpreter(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexEngine);
ParserInterpreter parser = pg.createParserInterpreter(tokens);
ParseTree t = parser.parse(pg.getRule(startRule).index);
System.out.println("parse tree: " + t.toStringTree(parser));
```

If you have the classes `JayLexer` and `JayParser`, however, you'd rather write something like:

```
ANTLRFileStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(fileName); // a character stream
JayLexer lex = new JayLexer(input); // transforms characters into tokens
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex); // a token stream
JayParser parser = new JayParser(tokens); // transforms tokens into parse trees
ParseTree t = parser.your_first_rule_name(); // creates the parse tree from the called rule
```

Then use the parse tree as you wish, for example a class implementing the `JayBaseListener` or `JayBaseVisitor`. Check one of the given links for more information.